# 3x3 Normal Form Payoff Matrix in LaTeX Tabular Environment

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays, bordermatrix

**~Disclaimer~** This question is a generalization of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249480/creating-a-payoff-matrix-using-latex-tabular-environment) to the 3x3 case.

I would like the same format as the top example in the answer to the above question; That is, "Player 1" on the left, "Player 2" centered on top, with three actions for each player ("A", "B" and "C"). I took the code as given and tried to add a column, but I clearly didn't know what I was doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player $2$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$} \\\cline{3-4}
  \multirow{2}*{Player $1$}  & $A$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\\cline{3-4}
  & $B$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\\cline{3-4}
  & $C$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It's almost right, except some lines are missing in the third column. Also, "Player 1" and "Player 2" are no longer centered. What changes do we need in order to fix these issues?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Replace the `\cline{3-4}` directives with `\cline{3-5}`
- Replace `& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player $2$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}` with `& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Player $2$}`, i.e., let `Player $2$` span all three columns
- Replace `\multirow{2}*{Player $1$}` with `Player $1$` and move the instruction down one row, to the row labelled "B".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Player $2$} \\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$} \\\cline{3-5}
            & $A$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\ \cline{3-5}
Player $1$  & $B$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\\cline{3-5}
            & $C$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\\cline{3-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

All the rules are drawn with the instruction `\Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
     &     & \Block{1-3}{Player 2} \\
     &     & $A$     & $B$     & $C$ \\
\Block{3-1}{Player 1} 
     & $A$ & \Block[hvlines]{*-*}{}
             $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\
     & $B$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\
     & $C$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]